# Admob ad page views much higher than impressions on tablets

Tags: android, admob

I have recently published an app to the Play Store with Admob ads. I noticed something odd today as my page views reported by AdSense were much higher than my impressions (7400 page views vs 1500 impressions). My match rate is still high (90%+) which suggests to me the ad requests are being fulfilled but the ads are not being displayed to the user. I then checked the platform information on AdSense to find that nearly all page views on 'high-end mobile devices' lead to an impression (1800 page views to 1500 impressions) whereas on 'tablets' I have 5600 page views to 13 impressions. This suggests to me that the ads are being displayed fine on mobile phones but barely at all on tablets.

What could be causing this? Are there any additional steps that must be taken to ensure AdMob ads are displayed on tablets as well?

Note: most of my ads appear as interstitials and some banner ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted a correlation between days I was updating and testing my app and days where the problem was happening. It turns out I had mis-copied my device ID when adding a test device to my ad requests so when I was debugging and testing the app, it was making many ad requests, although none were fulfilled as the app was signed with the debug key rather than my key, and the app is set up to re-request an ad if it fails after a short period of time.

Hopefully this helps anybody else with the same issue.